# Button makes an HTTP Request and Store the data in the database

Tags: php, html, mysql, asp.net, httprequest

I am not familiar with HTTP Request technology,  I did some search on the web for example I saw [w3schools article](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) about HTTP request but I didn't understand how I will make what I want to do.

To be more specific, I want a button in my website page to do an http request to another site (this one http://localhost/SensorPlatform/index.php) which inside the index.php contain this code/data.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

echo'{"ID":"SPID9999","RSSI":-48,"Time":"","sensors":[{"Type":"AirFlow","Unit":"Analog","Val":0},{"Type":"Temperature","Unit":"C","Val":28.65},{"Type":"SkinConduct","Unit":"microSiemens","Val":-1.00},{"Type":"SkinResist","Unit":"Ohm","Val":-1.00},{"Type":"SkinConductVolt","Unit":"V","Val":0.49},{"Type":"HeartRate","Unit":"BPM","Val":0},{"Type":"02 Saturation","Unit":"%","Val":0},{"Type":"ElectroCardioGram","Unit":"Analog","Val":3.78},{"Type":"BodyPosition","Unit":"^<>_|","Value":3}]}';

?>
```

What I want to do is that whenever someone is logged in to my site and click this button to check that if this $username has this $spid (ex: SPID9999) from table patient and then get the data  from the other site (http://localhost/SensorPlatform/index.php) and store it in my database table which is named as sensors.

Sorry that I don't provide any code but can't find what to do.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: You want to make this request when a form button is clicked and submitted to a PHP script?  The request will be made from PHP?

Comment: @Misunderstood I don't mind if the button is in form tags. What I want is to click this button , make the necessary if statements that check the username and spid and then store this data in my database

Answer (score 0):

Can I assume you can do the verification of the user?  I will for now.

The easiest way to make the request is a GET using `file_get_contents()`

```
$json= file_get_contents('http://localhost/SensorPlatform/index.php');
$data = json_encode($json,true);
```

The   `json_encode($json,true)`  give you an array of the JSON data.

The other is with curl which is a much more versatile and can do HTTP POST requests.  Once you get over the learning curve is simple and reliable.

This is the curl equivalent of the file_get_contents();

```
  $ch = curl_init('http://localhost/SensorPlatform/index.php');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILETIME, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 100);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,100);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
  $json = curl_exec($ch);
  $data = json_encode($json,true);
```

The curl setup here is for testing HTTP GET Requests.

```
  $ch = curl_init('http://localhost/SensorPlatform/index.php');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILETIME, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 100);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,100);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);

  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  if (curl_errno($ch)){
      $data .= 'Retreive Base Page Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
  }
  else {
    $skip = intval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE)); 
    $responseHeader = substr($data,0,$skip);
    $data= substr($data,$skip);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $info = var_export($info,true);
   }
  echo $responseHeader;
  echo $info;
  echo $data;
```

If you need custom Request headers add an array and an additional curl option:

```
    $request = array();
    $request[] = "Host: www.example.com";
    $request[] = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
    $request[] = "User-Agent: MOT-V9mm/00.62 UP.Browser/6.2.3.4.c.1.123 (GUI) MMP/2.0";
    $request[] = "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5";
    $request[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
    $request[] = "Cache-Control: no-cache";
    $request[] = "Pragma: no-cache";


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request);
```

If you need to do a POST Request:

Prepare the post data and add a couple of curl options:

```
$post = 'key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. 
In the first row did you forget the `' '` for the link because I am getting an error. Also i get this error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'curl_setopt' (T_STRING) in E:\xampp\htdocs\ptixiaki\ptixiaki.php on line 7`

Comment: got it, I can't see the errors until I post then I edit some more.

Comment: I forgot to write the `file_get_contents()` that's why i got the error.  Now I am getting this `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$json' (T_VARIABLE) in E:\xampp\htdocs\ptixiaki\ptixiaki.php on line 3` . Also all this code I place it in one file right?

Comment: Your request probably failed.  There is likely no JSON.  I need to see the code.  Please post your current code.

Comment: The code that is generating the error. `ptixiaki.php `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74776/discussion-between-niklakis-and-misunderstood).